# Send Post Data "mutlipart" from one Nodejs Function to another

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, multipartform-data, node-modules

I want to send to another app.post method the same data recieved in the bellow post method.

```
app.post('/sign_up', (req, res) => {
    var name = req.body.fullname,
    email = req.body.email,
    password = req.body.password,
    cpassword = req.body.cpassword;

    var base64Str = req.body.image;

    var obj = { name: name, email: email, password: password, cpassword: cpassword, b:base64Str };
    console.log("Server Recieved: ");
    console.log(obj);

    //Now here want to submit this data as post to another 
    //app.post("/get_data", function(req, res)) { //do something else   } )

});
```

Let me know how to achieve this?

Comment: Make a post request to that method.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a named function for the '/get_data' route and call that function at the end of '/sign_up' route.

See the sample code below.

```js
app.post('/sign_up', (req, res) => {
  var name = req.body.fullname,
    email = req.body.email,
    password = req.body.password,
    cpassword = req.body.cpassword;

  var base64Str = req.body.image;

  var obj = {
    name: name,
    email: email,
    password: password,
    cpassword: cpassword,
    b: base64Str
  };
  console.log("Server Recieved: ");
  console.log(obj);

  //Now here want to submit this data as post to another 
  get_data(req, res);

});

app.post("/get_data", get_data);

const get_data = function(req, res)) {
  //do something else
};
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you want to make a post request with the following data to another url in your site. This can be done using the [Fetch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch)

Answer (score -1):

You can try npm **Request** module.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/request#multipartrelated